# Link "Full page" under a code snippet appear in the flag dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-snippets, flag-dialog

On a post with a code snippet, if I click on **Run code snippet** then open the **flag** or **close** dialog on a post, the output and a *Full page* link are displayed, and I have this result:

[image]

Here is a code snippet in order to test this, the problem appear with this question too ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02Yyd.png)):

1. Click on **Run code snippet**
2. Open the **flag** dialog of this question and you
3. See that "Full page" is displayed

```css
p {color:Red;}
```

```html
<p>Hello, world!</p>
```

---

I use Firefox 44.0 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Duplicated on Windows 7 in Firefox 47.0, Chrome 50.0.2661.87 m

Comment: No repro Win 7 Chrome Version 51.0.2704.84 m : http://i.stack.imgur.com/iy36W.png

Comment: @NathanOliver Did you have the "Full page" link? You have to click on **Run code snippet**. You can try on this question.

Comment: @A.L That is what I was missing.  Repro after doing that.

Comment: Th css for `.snippet-code .popin, .snippet-code .popout` should have a  z-index of 9 or the close-popup z-index should be above 999 ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now fixed, it'll be live after our next production build.